# Sentiment Analysis Arabic Lexicons?

Tags: nlp, arabic, sentiment-analysis

I am searching for Sentiment Analysis Arabic Lexicons, so could you please help me to acquire them?
I want to ask also if I could acquire SANA lexicon?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might me want you want:

http://saifmohammad.com/WebPages/ArabicSA.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I need more

Comment: I just found that one by a simple google search "arabic lexicons sentiment analysis", you should be able to find much more. One thing, make sure to read the terms and condition of use of the lexicons. 

And, please, if your find my answer useful to your question considering give it a thumbs up.

Comment: Actually I found useful, But I am still newbie cannot thumbs up